# How to make rspec-mocks' expect to receive.with fail eagerly

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

[rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks)' `expect(target).to receive(:message).with(arg_matcher)` will only show an error at the end of the test if the target is invoked with parameters not matching the arg matcher passed to `with`. Is there a way to force it to fail eagerly - i.e., as soon as the target is invoked with non-matching params? RR works in this way.

The problem I am facing is that when I set up this mock with an arg_matcher as above, the test starts failing because the target is called with different params, but then another assertion fails before the end of the test, so I only see the error from this assertion, not from the missing mock (which would have shown me the difference between the expected params and the actually invoked ones).

Using rspec-mocks 3.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to make `receive` fail eagerly. However, `have_received` fails eagerly, so if it is the first of several expectations it will be the one that fails the test and that RSpec reports.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(baz)
  end
end

describe "RSpec" do
  it "reports a non-mock expectation failure before a mock expectation failure" do
    expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).with(1)
    expect(true).to be_falsy # RSpec reports this failure
    Foo.bar 2
  end

  it "reports a spy expectation failure when you'd expect it to be reported" do
    allow(Foo).to receive(:bar) # Spy on Foo
    Foo.bar 2
    expect(Foo).to have_received(:bar).with(1) # RSpec reports this failure
    expect(true).to be_falsy
  end

end
```

See [the documentation of RSpec spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies) for details.

This solution is probably best if

- if you prefer your tests in the logical [arrange-act-assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) sequence like I do
- if the spy expectation fails, you don't care about the other expectation
- if you mind the extra typing of the `allow` that sets up the spy less than you mind the `aggregate_failures` block

Regular mocks and Adarsh's solution are better

- you want to see the results of both expectations regardless of whether either fails
- if you mind the `aggregate_failures` block less than you mind the extra typing of the `allow` that sets up the spy

Answer (score 1):

> the test starts failing because the target is called with different params, but then another assertion fails before the end of the test, so I only see the error from this assertion, not from the missing mock

If I'm reading this correctly, you have multiple `expect` assertions in one spec and the first one is failing, so you're not seeing the second/third assertions failures?

If so, I'd consider using [RSpec's `aggregate_failures` introduced in v3.3](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures), which collect failures but run subsequent assertions:

```
aggregate_failures("verifying response") do
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  expect(response.headers).to include("Content-Type" => "text/plain")
  expect(response.body).to include("Success")
end

# Which gives you nice errors for all assertions

1) Client returns a successful response
     Got 3 failures:

     1.1) Got 3 failures from failure aggregation block "testing response".
          # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:18
          # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:10

          1.1.1) Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(200)

                   expected: 200
                        got: 404

                   (compared using ==)
                 # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:19

          1.1.2) Failure/Error: expect(response.headers).to include("Content-Type" => "application/json")
                   expected {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"} to include {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
                   Diff:
                   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
                   -[{"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}]
                   +"Content-Type" => "text/plain",
                 # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:20

          1.1.3) Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq('{"message":"Success"}')

                   expected: "{\"message\":\"Success\"}"
                        got: "Not Found"

                   (compared using ==)
                 # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:21

     1.2) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be(true), "after hook failure"
            after hook failure
          # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:6
          # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:10

     1.3) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be(true), "around hook failure"
            around hook failure
          # ./spec/use_block_form_spec.rb:12
```

You can also tag a describe block to `aggregate_failures`:

```
RSpec.describe ClassName, :aggregate_failures do
  # stuff
end
```

Comment: That's great info, thanks! But my problem was different - @Dave Schweisguth got it right.

Comment: Adarsh didn't quite restate your problem, but `aggregate_failures` does solve it: if you wrap your entire test in `aggregate_failures`, you'll see both the non-mock failure and then the the mock failure. (As I said above, whether you want to see the non-mock failure at all depends on what you're testing.)